# ng-click in directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**card-drawer.html (template)**

```
<div class="card-drawer-wrapper">
<div class="card-drawer-icon" ngClick="cdCtrl.toggle()">
    <i class="icon--{{ icon }}"/>
</div>
<div class="{{'card-drawer ' + (classesToAdd || '' )}}">
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

**cardDrawer.ts (directive and controller)**

```
declare var _:UnderscoreStatic;

class CardDrawerController {
static $inject = [];

toggle() {
    alert('toggled');
}
}

CardDrawerDirective.$inject = [];

export interface ICardDrawerScope {
icon: string
classesToAdd: string
}

export interface ICardDrawerAttributes extends ng.IAttributes {
icon: string
'classes-to-add': string
}

export function CardDrawerDirective():ng.IDirective {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'card-drawer.html',
    controller: CardDrawerController,
    controllerAs: 'cdCtrl',
    scope: true,
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link(scope:ICardDrawerScope, element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs:ICardDrawerAttributes, controller:CardDrawerController) {
        scope.icon = attrs.icon || 'pencil';
    }
};
}
```

**html (this is how i want to use it.)**

```
<div card-drawer>
        Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet
        risus. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
        Donec sed odio dui. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.                      
</div>
```

Comment: ...I'm presuming the name of the directive on the module is "cardDrawer"? Maybe you could post how you declare the directive on the module.

Comment: Are you getting anything or is it just a dead application?

Comment: @Gabriel Kunkel just the click event is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try `ng-click` in the div, instead of `ngClick` to invoke your fn.